# Without eval command does not run correctly

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

just something that i can't seem to figure it out. Begginner bash scripter here

I wrote a script to accept command line parameters that are later passed to maven

Here's is the working version of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

# deploys the application and runs acceptance tests against it
if [ -n "$1" ]; then
#Executes acceptance tests containing the word $1 - eg: ats paymill, will only run test scenarios with the paymill word
    echo mvn clean verify -Pacceptance.test -Dcucumber.options=\"-n $1\"
    eval $(echo mvn clean verify -Pacceptance.test -Dcucumber.options=\"-n $1\")
else
    mvn clean verify -Pacceptance.test;
fi
```

But I would expect that this would work:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

# deploys the application and runs acceptance tests against it
if [ -n "$1" ]; then
#Executes acceptance tests containing the word $1 - eg: ats paymill, will only run test scenarios with the paymill word
    echo mvn clean verify -Pacceptance.test -Dcucumber.options=\"-n $1\"
    mvn clean verify -Pacceptance.test -Dcucumber.options=\"-n $1\"
else
    mvn clean verify -Pacceptance.test;
fi
```

But the execution of the last script (with the -x flag) gives me the following output

```
+ '[' -n paymill ']'
+ echo mvn clean verify -Pacceptance.test '-Dcucumber.options="-n' 'paymill"'
mvn clean verify -Pacceptance.test -Dcucumber.options="-n paymill"
+ mvn clean verify -Pacceptance.test '-Dcucumber.options="-n' 'paymill"'
```

I can see the the result of the echo command is the one i expect, but if i try to run that instead of echoing it does not work.

Where does those quotes come from around the -Dcucumber.options and between the -n and the paymill words?

Thanks for any help, just can't figure it out this one

Comment: Why did you escape the double-quotes with back-slashes? This stops the quotes from having any special meaning, so the space becomes a parameter separator, as the shell expansion shows. If you want the quotes in the `mvn` run string, you should escape the space as well, to stop it from acting as a separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space after `-n` is not quoted nor backslashed, so bash performs word splitting on it. To prevent that, quote or backslash it. Once you do so, you can remove the double quotes, as the whole parameter is one word now:

```
mvn clean verify -Pacceptance.test -Dcucumber.options=-n\ $1
# or
mvn clean verify -Pacceptance.test -Dcucumber.options=-n' '$1
```

If the argument can contain whitespace, you should also consider doublequoting it.

```
mvn clean verify -Pacceptance.test -Dcucumber.options="-n $1"
```

Comment: Good point about spaces in `$1`: maybe the neatest solution is `"\"-n $1\""`. This makes sure that the whole string is a single parameter with quotes included in the expansion.

Comment: I thought about escaping the space but still it does not work: output with -x + mvn clean verify -Pacceptance.test '-Dcucumber.options="-n paymill"' There's still those single quotes around the -Dcucumber.options

Comment: @PedroGarciaMota: They are needed as they quote the space.

Comment: yes but i don't want them, they are most likely the cause of the script not running. If i use any of the options you gave me the maven execution crashes - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file or directory: /Users/pedrompg/Documents/quandoo/checkout_api/checkout-acceptance-test/"-n

Comment: @PedroGarciaMota: Please, use ` to quote code and error samples. Also, please show the command line that works for you.

Comment: @choroba sorry about that, directly on the terminal, without using the script this works: `mvn clean verify -Pacceptance.test -Dcucumber.options="-n paymill"`

Comment: What does `mvn clean verify -Pacceptance.test '-Dcucumber.options="-n paymill"'` return in the terminal?

Comment: Maven starts running and at the point it has to execute cucumber tests this happens:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file or directory: /Users/pedrompg/Documents/quandoo/checkout_api/checkout-acceptance-test/"-n`

Comment: OK, so what about `mvn clean verify -Pacceptance.test '-Dcucumber.options=-n paymill'`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19146/discussion-between-pedro-garcia-mota-and-choroba).

Comment: @PedroGarciaMota: Unfortunately, chat is blocked here.

Comment: well this works `mvn clean verify -Pacceptance.test '-Dcucumber.options=-n paymill'`=)
Thanks very much for the help @choroba, if you want, you can add this solution to your answer and i'll mark it as the correct one

Comment: @PedroGarciaMota: Updated.